# How to change fragments for Android application development, with buttons inside each fragments?

Tags: android, button, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have an Android activity that has two fragments inside, say A and B. I want to click buttons inside A such that B would be switched to C, D, or E.

The layout each refers to a .xml and the all layout have different buttons calling other other fragments or doing other stuffs....

now in main.java:

```
public void stackAFragment(int page) {

//depending on which button on the list is clicked, the corresponding fragment is replaced
if (npage = 1){
Fragment f = new FragmentB();}

if (npage = 2){
Fragment f = new FragmentC();}

if (npage = 3){
Fragment f = new FragmentD();}

FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
ft.replace(R.id.frag_content, f); 
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN); 
ft.addToBackStack(null); 
ft.commit();}
```

then in A.java, there is a list view, and for the listener

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
Main main = (Main) getActivity();
main.stackAFragment(arg2 + 1); }
```

and in B.java:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saved) {
View c = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_b, container, false);
return c;}
```

and in C.java:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saved) {
View c = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_c, container, false);
return c;}
```

and so on.....

So now, in the first page, it shows fragment A and B.

but when I clicked to change to fragment C, fragment B does not go away, instead, fragment C appears under fragment B

and when I clicked to change to fragment D, fragment C goes away but B still stays....

How could I solve my problem??

Thank very much!!! Highly appreciate if anybody could point me the right way.....

Additional information::::
the layout of main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frags"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SlidingMenu" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/frag_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    class="com.seapointcorp.enque01.ContentFragment" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/frag_title"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/titles_size"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.seapointcorp.enque01.TitleFragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: It would help to know where is the view with the id `R.id.frag_content` situated(maybe post the layout file as well).

Comment: You need to create a listener in your host activity, which you can call from fragment A and switch to your desired fragment.

Comment: R.id.frag_content is inside main.xml @@

Comment: Leandros:::: is there any links/ tutorials on that?? I don't think I understand....thanks!!

Comment: @user1702061 Will post some code, wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you're doing a replace `FragmentTransaction` using the id of a `Fragment` item from the layout file(so you basically make the replace in the fragment with id `frag_content`(which I assume is fragment B)). Instead you should have a wrapper layout(a simple `FrameLayout`, `RelativeLayout` etc) to act as an area to which the content fragment will be added/removed/replaced:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frags"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SlidingMenu" >

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content"     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <fragment
           android:id="@+id/frag_content"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           class="com.seapointcorp.enque01.ContentFragment" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frag_title"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/titles_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.seapointcorp.enque01.TitleFragment" />

    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Then in your `stackAFragment()` method you'll do:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
ft.replace(R.id.content, new tagetFragment()); 
 ft.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            ft.commit();
//...
```

Comment: ft.replace(R.id.content, f);   what is "f"?

Answer (score 0):

In your host `activity`

```
public static FragmentListener sFragmentListener;    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    // Do normal work.
    sFragmentListener = new FragmentListener();
    // Do more work.
}

public interface FragmentListener {
        void onNextFragment();
    }

    public final class FragmentListenerListener {

        @Override
        public void onShowNextFragment() {
            // Do Fragment Transition
            mFragmentTransition.replace(R.id.awesomeContainer, new A.class);
        }

    }
```

in your `Fragment`'s `OnClick` method just call: `HostActivity.sFragmentListener.onShowNextFragment()` to execute the method.

You can modify this to your needs.